# React Causes 404 when doing a refresh or entering URL manually

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having issues when trying to use React routers. I create a personal blogs and when I land on my homepage, I can easily navigate around and get my blog posts to load. However, when enter the URL manually, I get 404 page not found. After doing some Googlings, the solutions seem to be server-side rendering. What I am trying to understand is, as the first version of my app, I didn't need to worrying about the server side rendering and the posts still load fine (https://www.hqphu.com/posts/6kAWd9Mm6i9jXrkiE90tct). Im going to post my routers configurations from my first version and my latest version of the app so you can help me understand the root issues and what difference that they made.

First version App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/coming-soon" component={ComingSoon} />
            <Route path="/posts/:id" render={props => <IndividualPost {...props} />} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Latest version App.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout/>}>
      <Route index element ={<Home />}/>
      <Route path="about" element={<About />}/>
      <Route path="posts" >
        <Route
          index
          loader={blogsLoader}
          element={<Blogs/>}
        />
        <Route path="/posts/:id"
          element={<Post />}
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
 
  )
)

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
    <ChakraProvider >
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
  }
}
```

I understand Switch has been derprecated in React Router 6 so I can't really copy pastes from my own code. Before implementing Server-side rendering solutions, I want to understand how the issues arise.

Comment: `react-router-dom` is a client-side routing library. I don't believe SSR is the issue here. The server or hosting service just needs to be configured to return the root index.html file that is your app so it can be mounted and routing/navigation handles internally. How are you serving or hosting the app?

Comment: From the two solutions, apart from using different versions of React Router, the only thing that's different is your component for `/posts/:id`. Maybe you did not have a component named **<IndividualPost />** and it was actually **<Post />** like in the second one

Comment: @DrewReese I used Netlify to host my app. The first version seems to be loading fine but the second version is having trouble every time I refresh the page (or enter the URL manually). This is why I was confused why my first version works like a champ but the 2nd one doesn't. Do you have any solutions/resources you recommend?

Comment: @Airah No I just named the two components differently. These two versions are slightly different, but they both fetch specific posts from the id passed to them.

Comment: Can you [edit] to share ***complete*** [mcve] for both versions of the app code you are using? Did you make any backend/hosting service changes as well?

Comment: @DrewReese No i didn't make any backend services. I only have a simple API call to Contentful CMS to fetch blog posts.

Comment: @all I finally figured out. The issue seems to be with the hosting service Netlify. I was so focus  on my app that I didn't think it could be an issue from the hosting services. The solution I found was add `_redirect` file to the public folder, which redirects to the `index.html` file
```_redirects
/*   /index.html   200
```

Comment: I meant if you made any changes to the backend with respects to how you are hosting or serving the app.